# Android google play console error APK TRANSMIT USER DATA UNSECURELY

Tags: android, cryptography, google-play, google-play-console

My app uses user current location and address details, Once I completed my app I uploaded it to play store it works fine, I released three to four build without any issues. Last week I uploaded an APK and It's rejected from google play console and I got this below error

[image: Google play console error mail]

Then I changed my backend api call from http:// to https:// then I added privacy policy in login screen and Once I verified it works well then I uploaded again in play store, again app was rejected.

I googled about this error still I am not getting any solution to solve this issue.

Kindly help to fix it

Comment: I am having same issue. did you found solution ?

Comment: not yet bro, trying to fix it

Comment: @JigneshKanani Did you find any solution for this issue?

Comment: @MathaN No, still struggling.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here I have added the list that helped me to fix the same issue when I was faced.

```
1.) screenshots that you have added in Play Store store listing should not have user data.

2.) Change your api from http to https

3.) Privacy policy should be proper and you should mention proper information about why and how you are using user data. If you are
saving userdata in your server database you should that information
as well

4.) If you are using social media login you should add it in privacy policy (purpose of social media login).

5.) In login screen you should add read and accept privacy policy option.

6.) Make sure your server database is secured.
```

If still you are facing the issue if your app is in initial stage clear database data and then try once.